# Orchestration/notification of processing events

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have the following SCDF use case.

1. I have a couple hundred files to process and put in the db
2. A producer will get a single file, reads the first N number of rows and send it to source (rabbit mq) , then reads the next N number of rows and sends it to source again, etc, until done.
3. A consumer will receive these file chunks (from rabbit mq), do some minor enriching, and write it to the DB (sink)
4. I will have some number of streams > 1 running (say 4 for example) for some parallel processing of these files

My question is: Does SCDF have a mechanism to know when all consumers are completed (and hence the queue(s) are exhausted) so I can know when to start some other process (could be another stream/task/anything) that needs the db fully populated to begin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sink1 is the only consumer of source1. In a streaming application, there is no concept of “COMPLETED”. By definition, stream processing is logically unbounded and stream apps (sources and sinks) are designed to run forever. Tasks, on the other hand, are short lived, finite processes that exit when they are complete. The application logic defines when the task is complete. Processing a file, or a chunk of a file is the most common use case. A stream can monitor a file system, or remote file source such as sftp, or s3, and launch a task whenever a new file appears. The task processes the file and marks the execution as COMPLETE.

Answer (score 0):

This type of use case is better suited for task/batch. See https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/batch/sftp-to-jdbc/ which details the recommended architecture. You can use define a composed task to run the ingest and then the next task.

Comment: Thanks @dturanski, and pardon the newbie questions
Suppose if I have 4 deployments
source1|sink1,..,source4|sink4
source1 get a file and starts reading chunks to send downstream via source (rabbit). Is sink1 the only consumer bound to source1? 
    a) If sink1 is the only consumer of source1? Is this run marked as COMPLETED when sink1 has consumed all data? How do I know when all are done? When 200 exit statuses?
    b) If sink1 is not the only consumer source1, meaning sink2 is delivered a source1 payload, back to my original question/confusion - How do I know when all are done?

Comment: one final question @dturanski, suppose my sink1 task is designed to read until it drains all queue items produce by source1, then at that time send exit status completed. It is still not clear to me if I need to programmatically mark the payload as the "end/last" inside source so sink will know it is the last item or do I need some other mechanism for this?

Comment: You can, in theory, stream the file contents, as you suggest and signal the end. If you want to do that, SCDF may be overkill. Probably a standalone app is better (you can still use spring-cloud-task, spring-batch).  The recommended solution with SCDF is to pass the file path to the task. One task per file. So the task processes the entire file. It does not drain the queue items. If there is nothing in the queue, the task is not launched. Have a close look at the link I posted. The solution requires a shared file system (NFS mounted) or a remote resource accessed by different VMs.